# Create a 'lookup table' in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report already in CR2008 that is generated by using a Stored Procedure. Trouble is that this report will return some 'blank' prices due to some issue with our backend database....

What I need to do is include in this report a so-called 'lookup' table that has the items and costs so that if the report has a blank (null) cell then it goes and looks up in this seperate table.

Any suggestions on how I can do this??

Answer (score 0):

1. Change your stored procedure to look up missing prices or
2. If your lookup table is (not one-to-many!) related to your procedure output, then link it in Crystal Reports and use formula to calculate prices.

Comment: can you advise on how to link and recalculate in CR??

Answer (score 0):

Like arvo said, I'd change the stored procedure. Much easier to maintain then a crystal report + formulas. It almost sounds like you could do an

isnull(price, (select top 1 price from item where ....)) as price,